# Return one record per criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am struggling with a solution for getting one record per criteria.
In the attached example, I would like to get one record per "nbr".
I have started with this, but I cannot get what I need.

```
    SELECT t2.*,
        CASE 
            WHEN t2.duplicate_flag=1 AND (t2.country=t2.country_active OR t2.country=t2.country_inactive) THEN 1 ELSE t2.duplicate_flag END nbr_match
FROM
(SELECT t1.*,
        CASE d.duplicate WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 999 END duplicate_flag
FROM [Sheet1$] t1
JOIN
(SELECT nbr, COUNT(*) as duplicate
FROM [Sheet1$]
GROUP BY nbr) d
ON t1.nbr=d.nbr) t2
```

As I said, I would like to get one record per "nbr".
If I have one record per "nbr" it is OK and I will mark it with "1". For the others that have duplicates (count(*)>1), I will mark as "99" and then to modify these "99" based on conditions to get one record.
These are the rules that I have to follow in order to get one record per "nbr":

```
1. IF "country"="country_active" return me that row (per "nbr")
2. ELSEIF "country"="country_inactive" return me that row
3. If I have two the same countries between the "country" and the "country_active" THEN look at the MAX "expiration_date_active" OR MAX "expiration_date_inactive" and return me that record.
4. IF there is no match between "country"<>"country_active" AND "country"<>"country_inactive" return the column with the MAX date either from "expiration_date_active" OR "expiration_date_inactive"
```

The final table or output should look like:
[image]

Thank you in advance for help.

Original data:

Comment: I cannot add the excel file, so I pasted the whole table in the end of the question - Original table.

Comment: Don't post images of your data. Take the time to post it as DDL and DML statements, or at least tabular formatted `text`. Don't expect the users here to transcribe your data for you.

Comment: Please post it as fiddle or paste actual data.

Comment: I have deleted image data but still don't know how to add the table data here. I have created one here https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/, but if you can explain me how to paste it here. I am trying but it won't to paste as the original. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this provide the results you would expect ?

```
WITH ListOfNbr AS (SELECT DISTINCT nbr FROM [Sheet1$])
SELECT t2.* 
FROM ListOfNbr t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM [Sheet1$]
    WHERE nbr = t1.nbr
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN country = country_active   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
        CASE WHEN country = country_inactive THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
        expiration_date_active DESC,
        expiration_date_inactive DESC
    ) t2
```